# How to create a recording Span given a parent Span's traceId and spanId?

Tags: open-telemetry, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry-java

The data flow I am trying to instrument has a variety of in-band mechanisms for propagating context (SQS, Kinesis messages, entries written in a DB, etc.) In the process of manually instrumenting some components, I need to extract the context and create recording Spans which will reflect the work being done by those components. I have tried a couple of versions of this:

```java
Span parentSpan = Span.wrap(SpanContext.createFromRemoteParent(traceId,
                                                               parentSpanId,
                                                               TraceFlags.getDefault(), 
                                                               TraceState.getDefault()));

Context propagatedContext = Context.current().with(parentSpan);

Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("please-export-me")
                  .setParent(propagatedContext)
                  .startSpan();
```

However, the resulting `span` is of type `PropagatedSpan` and hence `isRecording` is `false`.

What is the correct way to solve this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out! The problem in the above code is in the `TraceFlags`. `TraceFlags.getDefault()` returns `0x00`, which marks it as not sampled. We need `0x01` - which is returned by `TraceFlags.getSampled()`. The code below works, with `span` now being the `SdkSpan` implementation, which is exported:

```java
Span parentSpan = Span.wrap(SpanContext.createFromRemoteParent(traceId,
                                                               parentSpanId,
                                                               TraceFlags.getSampled(), // NOT getDefault()! 
                                                               TraceState.getDefault()));

Context propagatedContext = Context.current().with(parentSpan);

Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("please-export-me")
                  .setParent(propagatedContext)
                  .startSpan();
```